# A criterion for area preserving dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, area, classical-mechanics

In my investigation of dynamical systems I was met with this seemingly easy question I could not find an answer to:

> If we have a two dimensional system of autonomous ODEs viewed as a 2D dynamical system:
>
> $\dot{x} = f(x,y)$
>
> $\dot{y} = g(x,y)$

Is there a simple way to check if this system is area preserving or not, possibly via the Jacobi matrix? I realize this may seem easy and ignorant of me to ask but I just need to know if there is a definitive simple answer. I assume f,g and infinitely differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area is preserved if and only if the divergence of the vector field $(f,g)$ is zero everywhere.